# Business intelligence Cube and Dimensions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

What I have to do to fix this problems? (I`m beginner in BI)

Errors

```
Error   3   Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        0   0   

Error   4   Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed IDbConnection interface was being used: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'..      0   0   

Error   5   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Karol s10016 Rafal s10017', Name of 'Karol s10016 Rafal s10017'.        0   0   

Error   6   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Kampanie Marketingowe', Name of 'Kampanie Marketingowe' was being processed.      0   0   

Error   7   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Id Kampanie Marketingowe' attribute of the 'Kampanie Marketingowe' dimension from the 'Karol_Rafal_Analysis_Servicies' database was being processed.        0   0   

Error   8   Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

Image

[image]

Comment: what did you do so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, the SSAS service user (`NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService`) cannot connect to the Data Source `Karol s10016 Rafal s10017` when you're trying to process the cube.

Make sure the SSAS service user can access this Data Source to prevent the error.